# Apache CXF/JAX-RS, Felix and Jetty

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, apache-felix

I have an existing group of bundles that together create a web application (including an instance of Jetty). A new requirement is to extend this application to provide a RESTful api (using JAX-RS).

I was able to develop the majority of the RESTful API in isolation, away from the rest of the applciation. Without realising, the Apache CXF bundle I was using contained its own Jetty instance. So, in isolation, this worked fine. When I merged the two halves of the application, the two instances' addresses conflicted.

This much I know for sure.

What I do not know is how to re-configure the RESTful API part of the application (JAX-RS) to use the existing Jetty instance. [This page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html) suggests the use of CXFServlet, but I cannot find much information on this.

Could anybody shed some light or point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I should also mention that, currently, my endpoints use the JAX-RS annotations in a Java interface to map between an endpoint and mapped class. I would prefer to keep this configuration method as opposed to XML or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

One option, which does not use Apache CXF, is to use the web components of Amdatu, which also support JAX-RS annotations. You can find more documentation about them at http://amdatu.org/components/web.html which explains how to setup your project with a separate Jetty instance. You might also want to watch the video at http://amdatu.org/howto/createwebapp.html which deals with the same subject.

If you really want to use Apache CXF, there are two versions: an "all in one" that is pretty much self-contained (and therefore also includes Jetty) and a "modular" one that consists of many separate bundles. The latter in theory gives you the option to integrate with your own copy of Jetty, but you need to figure out what exact set of bundles you need based on their documentation at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/index.html